# Continuous transformation with a propertie

Tags: analysis, continuity, manifolds

I have this problem but I don't know how to solve it. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ a continuous transformation that :
$$ ||f(x)-f(y) ||\geq \lambda||x-y ||$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and some $\lambda > 0$.

Prove that f is bijective and have a continuous inverse.  I have done the injectivity and i'm not sure about how to show the rest. 
Thanks
EDIT : Sorry, i had a $\leq$, is a $\geq$

Comment: this is false. The map $f$ could be the constant $0$ map, neither injective nor surjective

Comment: Why? If you have $||f(x)−f(y)||≤λ||x−y|| $ the 0 map does not fulfill that propertie.

Comment: $$ 0 \leq \lambda||x-y ||$$ is always true. Here we demand $\lambda > 0$

Comment: My bad, i had the wrong inequality there

Comment: The problem is done in one of the "Related" links on the right of your screen, in the case $m=n=1.$ Read that.

Comment: I don't know how to do the surjectivity :/ and there is a theorem of Local Inverse but I cant use it yet...

Comment: @WillJagy the zero map does not satisfy the inequality the O.P stated when $x \neq y$

Comment: Also i think that when $m \neq n$ then this spaces are not homeomorphic..Your posts wants to prove that $f$ is a homeomprphism

Comment: @MariosGretsas when I made the comment, the question had the inequality reversed.  Meanwhile, this question still has pre-image and image spaces of possibly differing dimension, so nothing is going to work properly. I do not know where this question arises, but it appears this person should stick with maps from the real line to itself.

Comment: Oh ok then @WillJagy..i did not know that your first comment was stated when the post had the typo..Indeed i also believe that the question is missing something or is not well stated